# Browser Prevent Pop Up Page in new window from ASPXGridview

Tags: vb.net, browser, popup, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a control URL Link Button in Gridview. The Link is dynamic and added ASPxGridViewCustomButtonCallbackEventArgs.
I use this code to redirect the link to another window. But the browser keep preventing it to open. Is there any way not to prevent the browser from opening it?

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "key", "window.open('" & xtsURL.Replace("'", "TempQuote") & "', '" & target & "');", True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the aspxcallback to open the link into another tab.